# Setting Drupal node select list field value programatically

Tags: php, drupal

I have a Drupal 7 node with custom fields. I can successfully set single values to a select list field programatically via the code in appendix 1. But I want to assign multiple values to this select list. (It has been configured to accept multiple values in the backend.)

**Question:**

What is the correct syntax to assign multiple values from a select list programatically to a Drupal node?

**Code I have tried:**

```
$node->field_referee_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'pending', 'declined';
```

The above code results in the below error:

```
*Parse error*:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in
*/home/scienceorg/public_html/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(125)
: eval()'d code* on line *77*
```

**Appendix 1:**

```
$node->field_referee_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'pending';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
$node->field_referee_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'pending';
$node->field_referee_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['value'] = 'declined';
```

You can obviously implement this in a loop if you need to iterate over many items